# A mathematics nazi is part of the mathematical inquisition?

Tags: phrase-request, word-formation, morphology

I learned that a [grammar nazi](https://www.dictionary.com/e/pop-culture/grammar-nazi/) is someone who seems extremely authoritarian in compulsively correcting people's grammar mistakes and other errors while practicing languages. And today I [learned](https://maxhalford.github.io/blog/bayesian-linear-regression/#bayesian-inference-with-colors) another phrase: mathematical inquisition.

> I’ve taken a bit of freedom with regards to the notation; if you’re part of the mathematical inquisition then take a chill pill.

I wonder 1) if I can coin a phrase like mathematics nazi to represent someone who cannot bear any freedom with regards to mathematical notations? 2) Is there already such a phrase or word? 3) Can I append a nazi to anything to represent someone who is very restrictive on that?

Comment: Yes, you have my permission (internet rando #202029) to coin such a phrase. Personally I wouldn't bother, though, because there are so many other better things in life to do than appending Nazi to yet another noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I wonder if I can coin a phrase like mathematics nazi to represent someone who cannot bear any freedom with regards to mathematical notations?*

Yes, this would be readily understood.  As a colloquialism it would probably be abbreviated to "math nazi" (US) or "maths nazi" (UK).  There is also some variation in practice regarding the word "nazi" - some people capitalise it (as almost everyone would when using it literally).

*Is there already such a phrase or word?*

Yes, by using a tool called "Google", I've been able to deduce that some people are already using "math nazi" and similar phrases.

*Can I append a nazi to anything to represent someone who is very restrictive on that?*

Potentially yes.  However, I'd inject a note of caution.  While the term "grammar nazi" may have become sufficiently widespread that people will understand that you are not being deliberately provocative (at least in informal contexts), this sort of metaphorical use of the term "nazi" could be seen as offensive, given that it might appear to be making light of a regime that murdered millions of people.

Comment: Many people would capitalise 'Nazi' when discussing the NSDAP which governed Germany from 1933 to 1945, and lowercase otherwise. I personally would avoid the word altogether when accusing someone of excessive authoritarianism with regard to conventions, rules, etc, lest I appear flippant, silly, or petulant. One person's grammar or maths nazi (or fascist) is another person's careful speaker or writer.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, and looking again, the dictionary.com source cited by the OP says at the end, if you scroll down far enough, "If you insist on being such a pedant, maybe call yourself grammar police instead of feeding the trolls?" - although I think this is rather unfair to pedants, since in the vast majority of cases the term "grammar nazi" is used by the pedants' critics.  (I don't doubt that a few people call themselves it.)  This bit seems to have been added by dictionary.com as an afterthought after spending five paragraphs using the term themselves and justifying it.

Comment: A Trip Adviser review for the 'World of Adventure' (a kind of fun-fair), which seems to have been added to Chessington Zoo since I was taken there as a child, said the visit was spoiled by (among other things) 'Health and Safety Nazi's [sic]'. The reviewer saw children denied rides because there was no adult with them. No doubt if some had been maimed, the criticism would have been in the reverse direction.  The place, and the zoo, were pretty dire in 1963, and don't seem to have improved. people who drive at the speed limit, or police who enforce it, are sometimes called 'speed limit nazis'.

Comment: In my first comment I think 'excessive zeal' would be a better choice than 'excessive authoritarianism'.

Comment: I wonder if the grammar police have an officer who didn't float up the Lagan in a bubble?